# jquery nextALL traversal

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-traversal

```
<div><a href="" class="deleteNextSomething">Delete Something!</a></div>
<div class="something">This is Something</div>
```

Obviously, I could just do this:

```
$('.deleteNextSomething').click(function() {
 $(this).parent('div').next('.something').remove();
});
```

But, what if my HTML is actually more like this:

```
<div><div><div><a href="" class="deleteNextSomething">Delete Something!</a></div></div></div>
<div class="something">This is Something</div>
```

Point is, I don't want to know how many parents I need to go UP before I start going ACROSS. I just want to traverse the DOM in a "next" direction" until I hit the next node I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how to solve this? pleasssse.

Additional info. In this next example, I would want it to delete Something1. So I can't say parents('div').next - because this would ignore the very next element.

```
<div>
    <a href="" class="deleteNextSomething">Delete Something!</a>
    <div class="something">This is Something 1</div>
</div>
<div class="something">This is Something 2</div>
```

Comment: and nextAll only looks at SIBLINGS. I want to look at "cousins" and "distant non-relatives, that just happen to be NEXT somewhere in the dom"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look at the "nearest" next, it would be something like this, using [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to go to *all* parents, instead of just the first level:

```
$('.deleteNextSomething').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('div').next('.something:first').remove();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/axtQ7/). Since they're in reverse order after the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) call, you want the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) one it finds, which would be the most local to the `this` you started with.

Comment: @captainclam - You're saying there may be no parent at all?

Comment: yeah... I know you will probably say "make a more consistent structure", which I understand. I'm just convinced there is an easy way to traverse the dom in a "forwards" direction

Comment: @captainclam - There isn't an "easy" way...and you should be aware that DOM traversal is *very* expensive...you're saying you have no control over the markup?

Comment: fair call. I think I'll just have two classes. deleteParentsNextSomething and deleteNextSomething. Thanks for the advice. Will accept your answer in a minute.